# Facebook api retrieve posts from a buy and sell group

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have looked all over the internet and have not found an answer.

I admin a buy and sell group on facebook and am querying the group/feed through the facebook graph api. If I post in the group as a 'discussion' post it shows up in the query results, but anything I post as a 'buy/sell' post does not come through in the query results. Is there anything in the graph API for querying buy/sell posts in a group?

Comment: did you check out the api reference already?

Comment: several times...

Comment: so, what did you find out?

Comment: same problem here, api reference only mentions feed and does not say it's limited to discussion posts

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem now. Before query with field 'feed' gave me all type of post from group, but now only discussion appear in response. Did you use 'posts' field?

Comment: posts field does not return anything for me, also it's not documented in the api reference

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem as of April 2020. Posts to a group which have a `sale_post_id` in the query string on their detail page come back from the `/feed` endpoint without any content, only an `id` and an `updated_time` parameter.

No documentation referencing Sales Posts appears to exist in the [Group Feed graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v6.0/group/feed).

As far as I can tell, there is no present solution for programmatic access to these post types.

Comment: In the Fall of 2022, looks like the interface to get sale posts is still not avail.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to include the field "attachments" to get the item for sale. In the following example, `6161166157241517_6161180003906799` is a post to a group containing a item for sale, "Gears".

I'm not sure how long the link will be valid for, but here's the UI link to that post: https://www.facebook.com/commerce/listing/1114583039178806/?ref=share_attachment

Making a `GET` request to this endpoint: `https://graph.facebook.com/6161166157241517_6161180003906799?fields=child_attachments,attachments,status_type,type`

Yields this response JSON (note that `child_attachments` and `status_type` are not included in the output)

```json
{
  "attachments": {
    "data": [
      {
        "description": "$500",
        "media": {
          "image": {
            "height": 541,
            "src": "https://scontent-ord5-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/325734407_702872891457106_7651211745488246974_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s720x720&_nc_cat=105&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=5bac3a&_nc_ohc=jYk_Nog1WEkAX_b9Q4z&_nc_ht=scontent-ord5-1.xx&edm=ADqbNqUEAAAA&oh=00_AfD3HFpQ-qLlq8Ru5FYAgn7L21aPnAe6NpvXdLd5rRIO0Q&oe=63C82336",
            "width": 720
          }
        },
        "subattachments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "media": {
                "image": {
                  "height": 541,
                  "src": "https://scontent-ord5-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/325734407_702872891457106_7651211745488246974_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s720x720&_nc_cat=105&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=5bac3a&_nc_ohc=jYk_Nog1WEkAX_b9Q4z&_nc_ht=scontent-ord5-1.xx&edm=ADqbNqUEAAAA&oh=00_AfD3HFpQ-qLlq8Ru5FYAgn7L21aPnAe6NpvXdLd5rRIO0Q&oe=63C82336",
                  "width": 720
                }
              },
              "target": {
                "id": "153887997464544",
                "url": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=153887997464544&set=gm.6161180003906799&type=3"
              },
              "type": "photo",
              "url": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=153887997464544&set=gm.6161180003906799&type=3"
            }
          ]
        },
        "target": {
          "id": "1114583039178806",
          "url": "https://www.facebook.com/groups/6161166157241517/permalink/6161180003906799/?sale_post_id=6161180003906799"
        },
        "title": "Gears",
        "type": "native_templates",
        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/groups/6161166157241517/permalink/6161180003906799/?sale_post_id=6161180003906799"
      }
    ]
  },
  "type": "status",
  "id": "6161166157241517_6161180003906799"
}
```