# Is it possible to fetch sale posts from facebook group using graph api

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have been using fb graph api to fetch feeds from fb group (being admin). 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/group/feed

It fetch all other feeds but not the sale posts.

Please advise if someone did this before or have any clues.

Comment: No, AFAIK these are not available. (Probably because Facebook wants to monetize this feature themselves.)

Comment: @04FS yes I see this, It does not fetch sale post specifically, other posts being fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a duplicate of [Facebook api retrieve posts from a buy and sell group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55107663/facebook-api-retrieve-posts-from-a-buy-and-sell-group), which appears to indicate that reading sale posts is not currently supported by the Groups API.